# How to fadeOut() right after append() jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a notification like facebook notification that appears in bottom left side. Now i have successfully appended the item, but i want it to fadeOut after 2-3 seconds. Something like this

```
$('.someclass').append().fadeOut();
```

Below is my code to append. I don't have an idea to fadeOut this

```
$('.notification_panel_parent').append('<div class = "panel notification_panel" id = "">'+

'<div class = "panel-body text-center">'+
'<span id = "notify_cand_name">'+data.msg.name+'</span><span> has been added</span>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be pretty simple to accomplish with jQuery.
If you give a closer look in the API you have the `delay` method, which allows you to run the next method after a small pause.

In your case it would be:
`$(ELEMENT).append(YOURCODE).delay(1200).slideDown()`

Link to Delay method jQuery Docs: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

They also have an example on the link provided, which can be easly addapt to your code.

**General Tipp:**
I would make a generator function to do all the stuff in the backside, so you can just provide your message and type of message (success, error, info) and you're good to go.

Comment: will affect parent container, not the appended item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the string, create a jQuery object that you can apply methods to and append that. Then use `delay()` before your animation and remove the element in the animation callback

```
var $note = $('<div class = "panel notification_panel" id = "">' +
  '<div class = "panel-body text-center">' +
  '<span id = "notify_cand_name">' + data.msg.name + '</span><span> has been added</span>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>')

 $('.notification_panel_parent').append($note);

$note.delay(2000).fadeout(function() {
  $(this).remove()
});
```